# Laravel 4 cache: will forgetting a key affect only single user or all user?

Tags: php, caching, laravel-4

Suppose I cached an Eloquent list query like this:

```
Article::with('comments')->remember(5, 'article_comments')->get();
```

When I update/delete that model, obviously I have to `Cache::forget('article_comments')` to generate/update a new list.

Now, in my app design, those update/delete only happens for a single user, so i was hoping the `Cache::forget('article_comments')` only forgets the current user's query list, not all users' in entire network.

So, my question is, will `Cache::forget()` deletes entire cache for all users, or only the cache in current user's computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will delete it for everyone. If you want to cache something for a specific user then the key will need to be unique for that user. Usually this is done by naming the key something like `article_comments_1`, where `1` is the users ID.

Comment: thanks for your answer, would it be a good practice to make cache for individual users? Estimated users are 50 at a time, estimated module is 10, 1 module would have 1 query cached (i only cache `Model->get()` queries), so there will be at least 500 queries cached

Comment: Only if it makes sense to do so. If it's not a taxing query you might not even cache it. You'll need to benchmark it and weigh up whether or not it's worth it.

Comment: then I'm guessing something that appears to every page is worth it, and something like appearing only on single page is not. Thanks for your answer ;)